# cant validate the input text in to do list

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, frontend

I am using node.js as the backend and using Axios  as a frontend to handle input and output to show to do list in the sidebar but i cant validate if (input.value !== '' ) i don't want only to show the check box in my side div also please help how i can delete to-do list after clicking the checkbox.

backend node/express :-

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
var arrs =[];
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('./font end'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))



app.get('/response',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({arrs});
})

app.post('/response',(req,res)=>{
const  {datas,id} = req.body;
let items = {datas,id}
arrs.push(items)
console.log(arrs)
res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./font end/index.html'))
})


app.delete('/response',(req,res)=>{
const  {id} = req.body;
arrs=arrs.filter((e)=>e.id !== id)
res.send(arrs)
})



app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server is listening');
})
```

font end code :-

```
const show = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const inp =document.querySelector('#datas');

const button = document.querySelector('#main-submit');
button.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
   
})

const jappy = async ()=>{
    try{
        
    let {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/response');
    let  rez = data.arrs.map((ak)=>{
        
        return `<div class="task"><span>${ak.datas}</span><input type="checkbox" id="checkit"></div>`;
        
    })
    show.innerHTML=rez.join('');

    }
    catch(err){
    console.log(err); 
    }}

   


jappy();
```

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100&display=swap');


*,::before,::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
:root{
    --input-width : 300px;
    --input-color:#f5f5f5;
}

body{
font-family: 'poppins';
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;

}

.sidebar{
grid-row: 1/3;
}

.task{
    margin-top: 10%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'poppins';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
}





#checkit{
   width: 1.6rem;
   margin-left: 7px;
   cursor: pointer;
}


.task>button{
   margin-left: 10px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.task>button:hover{
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(146, 146, 146);
}


.main{
margin-left: 200px;
}

form{
display: inline-flex;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-left: 10%;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    gap: 17px;
    flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   border-radius: 10%;
   border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
   box-shadow:0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(131, 131, 131, 0.25);
    padding: 25px;
}

#datas{
width: var(--input-width);
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    background-color:var(--input-color);
    outline: none;
}

#ids{
    width: var(--input-width);
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    border: none;
    background-color:var(--input-color);
    outline: none;   
}


#main-submit{
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #08C475;;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


#main-submit:hover{
box-shadow:0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(158, 158, 158, 0.45);
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To do app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="task">
    
    </div>
   
</div>

<div class="main">
        <form action="/response" method="post">
            <h1>TO DO app</h1>
            <div id="data">
            <label for="datas"><h3>item name</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="datas" id="datas" placeholder="type data">
            </div>
<div id="submit">
    <button type="submit" id="main-submit">click me</button>
</div>
 </form>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using (input.value.trim()) in the submit button also but value blinks for moment in the side div bar and disappear

I also used delete in the backend that uses IDs but  how can I adjust so i can only delete value of to do list after clicking input checkbox